# Blender not baking the right images

Tags: baking, ambient-occlusion

I'm new to blender so this is probably going to be a noob question. So I've been following Brackey's tutorial on a pow poly barrel. Because the tutorial is fairly old, I had to stray from it a little because I couldn't figure some of the stuff in the video out.

Right now, I have a barrel, made of 3 cylinders joined together (the actual barrel part, and 2 rings that go around the barrel). I have a different material selected for the barrel (brown color) and the 2 rings (black color), and 2 UV Maps, one for the barrel, and another for the rings. I also have an image for attached to each material, both of which are color grids.

I'm trying to bake ambient occlusion, as done in the tutorial, for the barrel part I the material for the metal rings is applied to the barrel and the barrel basically turns black. How can I fix this and why is this happening? Also, I'v tried baking the object as a whole, barrel and rings, and that just turns the barrel part white with some black at the top and bottom.

Comment: Are the normals facing the correct direction? (Overlays->Face Orientation, anything red means the backface is pointing outwards.)

Comment: The rings were red so I fixed that and for some reason if I try to bake, I get a message saying no valid objects selected.

Comment: Did you select the objects?

Comment: Yeah, objects are selected.